# Pixel 3 Android 12- Can't see Alert/Silent switch in app-specific notifications

Tags: applications, notifications, settings, alerts

I'm on a Pixel 3 running Android 12. See this screenshot, I'm trying to set this app to Silent notifications (In Settings > Notifications > App settings) but the option is no longer appearing:

[image: No Silent/Alert switch]

Comment: On my Pixel this Dialog has not changed by the update to 12. Just click in the channel name and you get the screen for selecting all the options like silent or vibrate.

Comment: Hiya Robert, to clarify, what is the "channel name" in this screenshot? Fwiw, I have noticed that the Alert/Silent feature is still available in the notifications tray when I long-press on a notification I've received. But I haven't been able to find the setting anywhere else.

Comment: In your sample screen shot the Instagram app has the notification channels `Instagram Direct`, `Instagram Direct requests` and `Instagram Direct video chat`. In Android such channels are defined/created by the app https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels